# Awaiting for a specified time asynchronously before deleting text channel discordpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, python-asyncio

I want to delete a discord channel after a few checks. But before doing so I want to send an embed message and then wait for 3 seconds. I want the waiting period to be non blocking. Is asyncio.sleep() a good way of achieving this? If so then how can I achieve this such that no new commands have to wait?

```
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    if delete_channel:
    asyncio.sleep(3)
    await ctx.channel.delete()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate `how can I achieve this such that no new commands have to wait?`?

Comment: >  If so then how can I achieve this such that no new commands have to wait?
This is not clear... What are you asking exactly?
In a separate matter, you are missing an `await` before `asyncio.sleep()`. Without it you're basically not doing anything meaningful.

Comment: I can't have asyncio.sleep without a loop. If I use time.sleep() instead then I'll be blocking this thread and the bot won't respond to any new commands.

Comment: why can't you have `asyncio.sleep` without a loop? Where did you get that from? You're not doing `loop.sleep`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `asyncio.sleep` is a non-blocking coroutine, as it runs - well - asynchronously. It simply suspends the current thread temporarily, while still allowing all other threads to run properly. Your only issues are indentation (this is not even close to valid indentation syntax), and `asyncio.sleep` is a coroutine, so you need to `await` it.